# Ordinary lookup and hiding

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, name-lookup

The following program compiles ([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Mfxe47)), but I don't understand, why.

```
namespace N {
    struct S {};
}


void Foo(N::S);


namespace Lib {
    template <class T>
    void Call() { Foo(T{}); }

    void Foo();
}


int main()
{
    Lib::Call<N::S>();
}
```

Shouldn't `Lib::Foo` hide `::Foo`? `Foo` in `Call` is a dependent name, and evaluation of dependent names are supposed to be postponed until the instantiation of the template. How does name lookup work in this case?

In namespace `Lib` `Foo(N::S{})` can be called before the declaration of `void Foo();`, but it cannot be called after the declaration, because `Lib::Foo` hides `::Foo`. `Lib::Call<N::S>();` is after the declaration, so when binding the name `Foo` here, hiding should be in effect, shouldn't it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but after some research: If `Foo` is nondependent, ordinary lookup and  ADL is executed in the template definition context. If `Foo` is dependent, ordinary lookup is executed in the template definition context, but ADL is executed at the point of instantiation. Our case is the second, thus `::Foo` is found by ordinary lookup. The `Lib::Foo` declaration does not hide `::Foo`, because it is after the context in which ordinary lookup searches. Someone please confirm my supposition, maybe in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All non-ADL lookup for a name used in a template is from the template definition, even though the results are not *used* until instantiation in cases where ADL might contribute declarations found from the instantiation context.

You can think of this in a “spatial” sense—the two parts of the dependent lookup happen from different places (limiting what they find) at the same time—or in a “temporal” sense—the non-dependent-ADL lookup happens while parsing the template, and the results are saved and later merged with the dependent ADL results during instantiation.  The former is how the standard describes it (to avoid describing compilation as a time-dependent process), but the latter intuitively accounts for the treatment of dependent names for parsing purposes (and thus when `typename` and `template` are required).

The standard rules for this are scattered across several cases for different kinds of names ([[temp.res]/1.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.res#1.3), [[temp.nondep]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.nondep#1), and [[temp.dep.candidate]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.dep.candidate#1) in C++20).

Comment: Thanks. Could you answer the actual question? E.g.: `Lib::Foo` does not do hiding, because a declaration of the name `Foo` is found (`::Foo`) from the definition of function template `Call`.

Comment: @Dr.Gut: `Lib::Foo` can’t hide anything in a lookup from a point where it hasn’t even been declared, which I explained is what happens here.

Comment: I suppose the first sentence "All non-ADL lookup for a name defined..." has a typo. The word "defined" should be "used", shouldn't it?

Comment: @Dr.Gut: Yes; the word “defined” must have crept in from “definition context”.  Editing.